# Open additional link in commandLink action

Tags: jsf

I have the following commandLink:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{orderForm.printOrderCards}"
    value="Print Document">
</h:commandLink>
```

The ActionHandler looks like follows:

```
public String printOrderCards() {
    try {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getResponse();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        String url = "http://nb200srv2016:8080/obt-documents/Artikel/2050/1007144_Rev.BA.pdf?allowCache=true&openDirectly=true";
        out.println("window.open(\"" + url + "\");");

        out.println("</script>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "go_printOrderCards";
}
```

There I want to open a URL in a new Window. After the Action should open a jsp-Page (`go_PrintOrderCards`).
The URL in the new window will be opened. But the new jsp-Page for `go_PrintOrderCards` will not be shown.

Can someone help me, how I can solve this?

Comment: The call of the javascript is working. But the CommandLink will after not naviagte to go_printOrderCards.

Comment: Because you already sent the html response yourself. You cannot (ever, http limitation, not JSF) send two different responses in one response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening a new window if condition true in managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688338/opening-a-new-window-if-condition-true-in-managed-bean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:

1) Change the return type of `printOrderCards` method to void like so:

```
public void printOrderCards() {
```

2) Remove all lines of code inside the `printOrderCards` method and add these lines inside the method:

```
String url = "http://nb200srv2016:8080/obt-documents/Artikel/2050/1007144_Rev.BA.pdf?allowCache=true&openDirectly=true";
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
requestContext.execute("window.open('"+url+"')");
```